# SQL - How to get result based on MAX date and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get a result for maximum `created_at` and for each `application_id` group. Below are the data sample,

```
application_id | checkpoint_id | created_at 
1              |  260          | 2018-12-28 11:54:52    
11             |  259          | 2018-12-24 18:16:30    
11             |  260          | 2018-12-26 17:48:58    
12             |  260          | 2018-12-26 17:48:58    
12             |  261          | 2018-12-26 18:00:00
```

The result that I want is only for `checkpoint_id = 260`. For example, the result above that I want is `application_id` no. 1 & 11.

The query that I tried,

```
SELECT * FROM histories h 
WHERE `checkpoint_id` = 260
AND created_at = (
  SELECT MAX(`created_at`)
  FROM histories
  GROUP BY h.application_id, h.checkpoint_id
)
```

**Result**

```
application_id | checkpoint_id | created_at 
1              |  260          | 2018-12-28 11:54:52
```

I am expecting to get 2 rows for id no 1 and 11. Is there a way to do it.

> Update on latest query

Just to update on my latest query that I achieved to get the expected results. The query is as below,

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT application_id, checkpoint_id, created_at 
    FROM histories 
    GROUP BY application_id, checkpoint_id
) AS h 
WHERE h.checkpoint_id = 260 AND h.created_at=(
    SELECT MAX(`created_at`) 
    FROM histories h2 
    WHERE h2.application_id=h.application_id    
)
```

Comment: What a difference between app_id 11 and 12? Why not 3 row 1,11,12 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM histories h 
WHERE h.checkpoint_id = 260 AND
      h.created_at = (SELECT MAX(h.created_at)
                      FROM histories h2
                      WHERE h2.application_id = h2.application_id AND
                            h2.checkpoint_id = h.checkpoint_id
                     );
```

Your version is just comparing each `created_at` to a `created_at` that is the maximum for *any* application/checkpoint combination.  You want the one that is specifically for your combination.

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```
SELECT * 
FROM histories h 
WHERE h.checkpoint_id = 260
order by h.created_at desc
LIMIT 1
```